# How to wordpress random posts in tag.php?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show random articles on the tags page on my wordpress site, how can I do?

I did a few edits to the functions file, but it didn't work

```
function one_random_post_on_home_page( $query )

{

    if ( ! ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) )

   return;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'one_random_post_on_home_page' );
```

again only one article appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement is ending the execution of the function before your edits to the query. Also, your conditional is looking for anything but the tag archive and main query by using the ! in your code. The solution below is working for me.

```
function randomize_tag_archive( $query ){
    if ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts','randomize_tag_archive' );
```